# Error message when willing to resize a view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a stackview in Swift defined in Interface Builder:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myStack: UIStackView!
```

Later in the code:

```
myStack.frame.height=100 -> Error:Value of type '(CGRect) -> CGRect' has no member 'height'
```

The member height exists because the autocomplete of XCode proposes it.
What is this CGRect error?

Comment: Use this:  myStack.frame.size.height = 100.0

Answer (score 1):

In docs of frame ( CgRect)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1455645-height

```
var height: CGFloat { get }
```

it's available as a getter only while in docs of CGSize

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgsize/1455076-height

you can set it

```
myStack.frame.size.height = 100.0
```

Or

```
myStack.frame.size = CGSize(width:height)
```